# how to Validate captcha before submit a form in joomla

Tags: javascript, captcha, client-side-validation, joomla3.5

> I have installed 5 captcha plugin in my joomla site and i set  any one
>   captcha out of 5 in com_users configuration in backend of joomla.
>
> ---

So I want to validate that captcha from client browser in registration form.

```
client side validation for every captcha from client browser
```

Comment: This question has also been posted at: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/17817/120

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google's reCaptcha that is the default plugin for Joomla!, the validation is done off site and a pass or fail "flag" is returned to your form...no further action needed from you.

Comment: It may be any custom captcha group of joomla plugin

Comment: So, you are trying to write your own captcha plugin?

Comment: I developed a component view which is custom user registration and I set captcha field in back end configuration.

Comment: So, your custom component randomly selects a "captcha" plugin out of a list of 5? The plugin itself, whichever is selected, should still be passing a validation flag to your form.